# Defer function in golang not executing a for case in select

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

This program runs a function `LongRunningTask` in a go routine called from `main`. It creates or opens a file, then waits for 5 seconds, writes to the file and then the deferred function in the end closes the file and writes to the channel.

`main` listens on this channel and once it gets a message it then exits the application.

Now if run this program and don't interrupt by pressing ctrl+c on the keyboard it gives the output as follows which is right - but it does not run the deferred function in the end here which is responsible for closing the file and printing a message.

```
successfully written to file..
writing to channel
Exiting application
```

And if I run the same program and press ctrl+c within 5 seconds, it receives a shutdown signal as expected and then runs the deferred function, writes a message to the channel and exits. The output it as follows

```
^CReceived a shutdown signal
long running task cancelled.. exiting now..
writing to channel
file closed successfully..
Exiting application
```

Program code

```
package main

import (
  "context"
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "os/signal"
  "time"
)

func LongRunningTask(ctx context.Context, c chan bool) {
  file, err := os.OpenFile("data.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error opening the file - ", err)
    return
  }

  defer func() {
    if err := file.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error closing the file - ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("file closed successfully..")
    }
  }()

 select {
 case <-ctx.Done():
    fmt.Println("long running task cancelled.. exiting now..")
 case <-time.After(time.Second * 5):
    message := []byte("sample data")
    _, err = file.Write(message)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error writing to the file")
    }
    fmt.Println("successfully written to file..")
 }

 fmt.Println("writing to channel")
 c <- true
}

func main() {
  ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

  s := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
  signal.Notify(s, os.Interrupt)
  go func() {
    <-s
    fmt.Println("Received a shutdown signal")
    cancel()
  }()

  c := make(chan bool)

  go LongRunningTask(ctx, c)

  <-c

  fmt.Println("Exiting application")
}
```

If i move `c <- true` inside the deferred function, then the deferred function gets called irrespective of the first or 2nd case in `select` but otherwise the deferred function is only called in the first case of `select`

I understood that when I move the channel writing logic inside the deferred function, it will always work for both the `select` cases as `main` is blocking on that channel but what I don't understand is if the writing to channel logic is outside of the deferred function where it's originally in the sample code above, then why is the deferred function only called when the first case inside `select` is matched and not the on second one?

Comment: If you write to the channel outside of `defer`, the main goroutine can exit before the defer is executed. Always `defer` the mechanism you are using to wait for goroutine completion (usually `Done()` on a `sync.WaitGroup`)

Comment: Thanks @JimB but from my observation every time I ran this program, defer always executed if the case selected in select was the first one `<- ctx.Done()` but it never executed when the case selected was the second one which made me wonder why is it behaving that way?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. if you don’t wait for the goroutine to complete, the defer may or may not print something depending on how quickly the program exists